# Chrome developer tool - Remove unnecessary header in network tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Can I have less header in network tab? (picture)

[image]

Comment: please marks as best answer with green check marks so other can find easily

Answer (score 1):

The Requests table displays the following columns by default:

- **Name** The filename of, or an identifier for, the resource.
- **Status** The HTTP status code.
- **Type** The MIME type of the requested resource.
- **Initiator** The following objects or processes can initiate requests:

  - **Parser** Chrome's HTML parser.
  - **Redirect** An HTTP redirect.
  - **Script** A JavaScript function.
  - **Other** Some other process or action, such as navigating to a page via a link or entering a URL in the address bar.
- **Size** The combined size of the response headers plus the response body, as delivered by the server.
- **Time** The total duration, from the start of the request to the receipt of the final byte in the response.
- [Waterfall](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#waterfall) A visual breakdown of each request's activity.

---

Add or remove columns

Right-click the header of the Requests table and select an option to hide or show it. Currently displayed options have checkmarks next to them.

Comment: Thank you for your detail, but I couldn't find the hide/show check box. After right click, it just shows list of header info like method, status, etc but nothing changes after I modify the check.

I'm using latest chrome, maybe issue with it?

Comment: please right click on any column and click on reset column **OR** uninstall and install it again